# Migrate .NET Framework To .NET Core - Web App With SQL Server RLS Impersonation

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-core, iis, impersonation

I have designed a .NET Web Application which runs on Windows IIS over our company's intranet.

It is a very simple application hosting numerous editable datatables.  Users are provisioned through Windows Authentication so they are automagically able to access the web application based on their defined access rights.

All table data is hosted in a SQL Server database.  There is a specific table within the database that references the type of access each user is provisioned to see.  Windows IIS is setup to run with ASP.NET Impersonation so that all queries are run impersonating the user's rights rather than the apps rights.

For example, below is how the access table is defined.

**UserAccess**

| UserAccessId | User | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | WindowsDomain\UserOne | Italy |
| 2 | WindowsDomain\UserOne | Mexico |
| 3 | WindowsDomain\UserTwo | Italy |

Subsequent tables are designed with a foreign key relating back to this **UserAccess** table.

**CityPopulation**

| CityPopulationId | City | Country | Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Puebla | Mexico | 9,209,944 |
| 2 | Tijuana | Mexico | 1,810,645 |
| 3 | Rome | Italy | 2,617,175 |

There is then an access predicate that is defined which checks the current Windows user to the UserAccess table and then filters/blocks all subsequent SELECT/UPDATE queries through the web application based on that user's rights.

In this example. UserOne would be able to see the entire **CityPopulation** table while UserTwo would only see record #3.

This method has allowed all of the security to be handled within SQL Server while eliminating the need for users to ever enter any type of credentials.

The problem is .NET Core does not implement Windows Impersonation.

> Apps run with the app's identity for all requests, using app pool or process identity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation

While we are still relatively young in the implementation of this application, I'm wondering if we should consider a better design to how we're leveraging Windows Authentication as it relates to our security.

The key design concepts are:

1. Windows Authentication a must.  No typing in credentials.
2. Based on a user's login, a user will have unique rights to see specific rows of tables.

Should we stick with .NET Framework and not worry about future proofing with .NET Core?

Is what we did in .NET Framework a logical design for long term growth and stability?

Are there better alternatives and way to design/implement a table that must meet the above mentioned criteria?

Is there a way to acheive the above mentioned criteria in .NET Core without having to modify code at the application level?

I'd be interested in hearing people's thoughts, design ideas, etc.

Comment: You might stick to .NET Framework for now, but the world is moving away from the Microsoft centric .NET Framework/Windows authentication/impersonation as a whole toward open standards.

Comment: `The problem is .NET Core does not implement Windows Impersonation.` I think that sentence is just plain wrong. Your link shows how it works. And `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated` is available and works just fine in .NET Core.

Comment: @LexLi What are the alternatives to Windows Authentication in a Windows Intranet application where we do not want the user to have to type in their credentials?

Comment: @PMF You're right, my wording was misleading/incorrect.  What I meant to say was .NET Core is not natively implemented as it is in .NET through IIS with a basic checkbox in the IIS settings.  There is a bit more work involved to get impersonation working through ASP.NET Core

Comment: It is difficult to slove your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.